# "Should character education be part of the curriculum that perspective teachers are exposed to in their credentialing program?" — is this too wordy?

Tags: redundancy

> Should character education be part of the curriculum that perspective teachers are exposed to in their credentialing program?

Comment: 1. Proof-reading is OT. 2. "Wordiness" is both subjective as well as context-dependent. 3. The question has no grammar issues. (What do the others think?)

Comment: I’m inclined to let the question stay under the new tag of redundancy.  You're right that there's no question of grammar here, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: Why just art teachers? I believe you mean to use the term 'prospective' instead. This is one of the problems with using four bit words when one'll do.

Comment: I am not sure it is adequately verbose for the field of education.  Try "Should character education be integrated within the pre-service curriculum to which prospective teachers are exposed in the normative and/or formative credentialing program(me)?"

Comment: It might not be a _grammar_ issue as such (more of a semantic one), but there definitely seems to be something not quite right about those ‘perspective teachers’. Unless people who are to teach you some perspective are required to be formally credentialled nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of opinion (as per Kris’ comment on the question), but: yes the sentence as given is verbose.  First, if a curriculum is for prospective (not *perspective*) teachers, then it is part of their credentialing program; hence that (frankly rather ugly) phrase is redundant.  And, second, if a curriculum is for prospective teachers, then prospective teachers are necessarily exposed to it; so, *are exposed to* is redundant too.  Removing these, and using *for*, we have:

> Should character education be part of the curriculum for prospective teachers?

Same meaning, 40% less wordage. Even punchier:

> Should character education be on the curriculum for prospective teachers?
>
> Should character education be on the prospective teachers’ curriculum?

The last one is 50% shorter than the original.

Comment: I presume it’s not intentional, but I almost rather like how you turned a curriculum for prospective teachers into a curriculum prospective [in the archaic sense of ‘prospect’] for teachers in the second example. :-D

Comment: Janus: thanks, quite unintentional.  Can't believe how many typos slipped through!

Answer (score 1):

".. prospective teachers..."

Otherwise, not too wordy.   It contains four concepts:  character education,  the curriculum, perspective [sic] teachers, credentialing program".

Daniel's last version is excellent; it's concise.  (Ilm sure he meant the "be" to be there.)

I'd nit-pick and suggest "Should character education be on **the** prospective teachers’ curriculum?

Comment: Good observation re insertion of _the_.  It kills the ambiguity.  Upvoted your answer, and I'll now amend mine.

Comment: Funny, I was about to suggest removing the ‘the’. It makes is _more_ ambiguous to me, making it sound like it’s the curriculum that is prospective, rather than the teachers.